# getting a Reactjs repo onto Github Pages

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, github, webpack

I have a repo that has already been established, meaning a complete Reactjs application is in the repo. I want to be able to go to username.github.io/repo and interact with my application, but I get only a 404 page.

I have read documentation and talked to colleagues and the only clarification I got is that despite how Github Pages encourages you to create a repo called username.github.io, I do not need to do that because Github gives me the .github.io for free.

That has not helped me figure out why I cannot access my app via the url.

Its an Reactjs application I already have created in the past. I just learned today that you can have your repos hosted on Github pages and thats all I want to do. Please help.

This is what I have done so far. I have a repo with just the repo name, in other words the repo is not called username.github.io as instructed on Github Pages site. Its just called myApplication

In the package.json file I have added the url:

```
{
  "name": "redux-simple-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple starter package for Redux with React and Babel support",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:<username>/<repo-name>.git",
  "homepage": "https://<github_username>.github.io/<myApplication>/",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
```

This is my file structure in my repo:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an `index.html` in the root directory of your repo?

Comment: @1290, I actually do, yes.

Comment: @1290, if you'd like you can add the documentation you provided as the answer and thank you.

Comment: Sure I have posted it below

Comment: Take a look at this:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages