# Deploying a Reactjs app to Github Pages

Tags: node.js, git, reactjs, github, github-pages

I am trying to get my Reactjs app onto Github Pages, but all the documentation I have found assumes you created the application via

```
create-react-app
```

I created my application via

```
npm init
```

If I am not mistaken for the former you do

```
create-react-app --save react-scripts@version
```

which allows for the following of this documentation:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages

Does anybody know if it is possible to have a Reactjs app on Github Pages where the initial app was created via npm init?

So this questions is different from the similar question posted as duplicate because the documentation given as the answer would work if the project would have been created with

```
create-react-app
```

It does not apply to my situation where my Reactjs app was created with

```
npm init
```

So hopefully a resolution, if there is one would help all those who initiate their SPAs with npm init to deploy to Github Pages or Heroku which also requires create-react-app to happen in the beginning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting a Reactjs repo onto Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737008/getting-a-reactjs-repo-onto-github-pages)

Comment: npm run build, and then point to the build dir index.html

Comment: so the index in public folder is not a static web page. You have to build it using npm run build.

Comment: @Jason, so after I run npm run build on my repo react application, it will then display in Github Pages? I ask because I get this error if I do that "missing script: build".

Comment: @Ale a missing script can be caused by incorrect Webpack setup. Check your package.json. And yes I think you will be able to get it work after build and specifying the public folder for git pages.